# ASP.NET MVC post won't sent values to SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I'm trying to create a signup page, but I can't get the values sent to my database.
I don't get any errors so I can't figure out what is wrong.

The model:

```
public class AddNewUser
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string usermail { get; set; }
    public string usertype { get; set; }
    public string userpassword { get; set; }
    public bool userterms { get; set; }
}
```

The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Opretbruger(AddNewUser user)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string username = user.username;
            string usermail = user.usermail;
            string usertype = user.usertype;
            string userpassword = user.userpassword;
            bool userterms = user.userterms;

            string usersub = "Test";

            DateTime createdate = DateTime.Now;

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Helpers.ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.CommandText =
                   "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_email, user_type, user_password, user_subscription, user_terms, user_createdate) VALUES (@username, @usermail, @usertype, @userpassword, @userterms, @usersub, @createdate)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = username;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@usermail", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = usermail;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@usertype", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = usertype;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@userpassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userpassword;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@userterms", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userterms;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@usersub", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = usersub;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@createdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = createdate;

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }

        return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it into try-catch block and display error in console (Maybe it will help you). Anyway IMO better would be entity framework to do anything with database (Use ORM).

Answer (score 0):

Probably this couldn't be solution but you can correct the order of inserting data and try:

"INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_email, user_type, user_password, user_subscription, user_terms, user_createdate) VALUES (@username, @usermail, @usertype, @userpassword, @usersub, @userterms, @createdate)";

And as best practice, try to catch exception which will help you to understand the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to change:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@userterms", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userterms;
```

To:

```
   sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@userterms", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = userterms;
```